# Cannot open chrome on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, desktop-computer, debug

I have used chrome normally on my PC for years, but now when I click the sidebar icon, desktop shortcut, and even when I run as admin from Windows Explorer, literally nothing happens.  I tried opening task manager, and there weren't any hidden chromes running anywhere.  Restarting did nothing.  How do I fix this?  The start new task in task manager and command lines also do nothing when told to run chrome.

Comment: Try a new data folder from command line like: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --user-data-dir="D:\temp\ChromeData". If still not working then copy chrome install folder to another place like copy "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application" to another place and use a new  data folder to start it, if still not working, then OS-reinstall may be the choice

Comment: You can check if Google Chrome is still installed in Control Panel > Programs > Programs and Features. If Chrome doesn't work or is not installed [download](https://www.google.com/chrome/) it and install it again

Comment: @spike_66 Its there and definitely installed